# Limit the number of lines/rows for user input Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, css

My text area:

```
<textarea id="ta"
                name="message"
                rows="4"
                cols="40"
                maxlength="100">
```

I want to limit a user from typing more then the rows specified.  To clarify, the user shouldn't be able to type in more then 4 lines of text.  Currently I can keep hitting the enter key in the textarea field and it will just generate a scroll bar and keep going down.  I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const maxRows = 5 
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
let rows = 1 

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) rows++   // count rows
  
  if (rows > maxRows) {
    e.preventDefault()    
  }
})
```

Comment: Only flaw I see is if a user wants to delete a line while editing their input, the code doesn't account for that, so potentially one you run out of enters, you're stuck unless I add a clear button or something like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).